# How to print a specific HTML image

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

I am trying to make a button that when pressed prints an image that is added to the code as a link. How can I do that?

The code below prints the whole page, but I want it to print only a specific image.

```
<a href="javascript:if(window.print)window.print()">Print</a>
```

Comment: While you are looking for a js solution, just note that you can set CSS print options to hide all document, and display your image.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use a print `@media` query to hide all images and whitelist only the clicked image. With a little `JavaScript`, we can dynamically create a print query and attach it to the page's `style` tag.

First, I'm surrounding each `img` in a `button` element, since the anchor isn't really a good semantic option here. Buttons do things; anchors take us places.

Next, in the `JavaScript`, we attach a click handler to each button, grabbing the id of its child image. We then create a new print media query, **wiping the old one out** if it had existed. In our dynamic snippet, we're feeding in our `imgId` variable, containing the id of the image we want to show. All other images are not displayed.

Finally, the print event fires. We're done and only the desired (clicked) image makes it to the print preview.

```js
const buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");

function buttonHandler() {
  const imgId = this.querySelector("img").getAttribute("id");

  document.querySelector('style').textContent =
    `@media print {
        img { display: none; }
        #${imgId} { display: block; }
     }`;

  if (window.print) {
    window.print();
  }
}

buttons.forEach(button => {
  button.addEventListener("click", buttonHandler);
});
```

```html
<button><img id="img1" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300" alt=""></button>
<button><img id="img2" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/200" alt=""></button>
<button><img id="img3" src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/250" alt=""></button>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xw2zbL6f/1/